# CKeditor 3.0 Custom CSS and invisible HTML tags

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, rte

I have a web page with structure:

```
<head><link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
    Some RTE text from CKEditor.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</head>
```

I was able to define custom CSS file in config.js:

```
config.contentsCss = '/main.css';
```

But, since my page structure is `<body><div class="wrapper"><div class="content">`
CSS definitions ".wrapper .content" are not applied as should be.

Ofcourse, if I add those in the source, it is working fine, but in that case when I save it, it has been doubled.

Is it possible to somehow define it in CKEditor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is your problem? Does `config.contentsCss` solution work for you?

Comment: No, because there are no DIVs classes "wrapper' nor "content" in RTE. And I do not need them in RTE because they are in layout.